# Django project on AWS elastic beanstalk always has health "severe" and CPU load 100%

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've developed a web app using python and django and have deployed it to AWS elastic beanstalk and have been having problems.

I followed this tutorial on how to deploy and followed the steps:
http://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/05/23/tutorial-django-elastic-beanstalk/

The deployment worked for a couple of days and was reachable on the url given by elastic beanstalk, but today it stopped working and I noticed some weird log entries.

My health is always "severe" and my CPU load is always at 100% (user: 90+%)

here are the logs from elastic beanstalk:

https://pastebin.com/1KvSP6SJ

```
What is this /cpv, and why is there so many requests for it? At one point 
there were +200 r/sec.
I also don't know what cpvfeed.50onred.com is. it is not my domain, nor am I 
using any kind of advertising site.
```

Is this some sort of attack, or am I doing something wrong?

My website is not working and is giving me HTTP 408 and HTTP 504 errors.

How can I make my site reachable again, and bring the CPU down to a normal value. I should only have about 3-4 users at the moment, so I don't know where these +200 requests per second are coming from.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: what is `cpvfeed.50onred.com`? Is this your domain or the advertising site? Something is going on with `click per view` but you will need to provide more details (edit your question) about what you have setup and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know what that is, that's part of my confusion... I don't know if it's an attack of some sort maybe? It has a bunch of requests from random IP's (see log). I've added more information, let me know what else would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Terminate the instance and start over. I would not take the chance that you have been hacked.

Comment: @JohnHanley... This morning everything is back to normal, my site is available, and the health is now "OK" there is no more cpvfeed.50red.com requests... now my log is https://pastebin.com/9DZJ4Zdp... I can now see: "[Wed Oct 03 07:58:54.987259 2018] [:error] [pid 3389] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '52.0.10.167'. You may need to add '52.0.10.167' to ALLOWED_HOSTS." but I don't know what that IP address is... could it be something from amazon?

Comment: Your were under some kind of attack that I don't recognize. The HTTP Host header is used to specify the name of the web site (domain name) as a single IP address can serve more than one web site. Hackers often use IP addresses to go directly to servers as they don't care about the domain name. This is normal bad traffic. Time for you to implement a web firewall.